# Create a background process with system tray icon

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, background, system-tray

I'm trying to make a Windows app that checks some things in the background, and inform the user via a systray icon.

The app is made with Not managed C++ and there is no option to switch to .net or Java.

If the user wants to stop the app, he will use the tray icon.

The app can't be a Service because of the systray side and because it must run without installing anything on the user computer ( it's a single .exe )

Using the typical Win32 program structure ( RegisterClass, WndProc and so on ) i dont know how can i place some code to run apart the window message loop. 
Maybe i have to use CreateProcess() or CreateThread()? Is It the correct way to handle the Multithreading environment?

If i have to use CreateProcess()/CreateThread(), how can i comunicate between the two threads?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Your question is actually many questions. 1. How do I create a background process ? 2. How do I make two threads/processes communicate ? 3. How do I create and use a system tray icon ?

Comment: You're right. i Think the number 2 is the more complicated :)

Comment: Indeed... And I think you'll be more successful in getting helpful answers if you address those issues separately :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the system tray icon, you'll need Shell_NotifyIcon.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the the systray icon side was more clear than the threading issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want to create new processes to do this, you want to create a thread in your application. The API to do this is [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx). But if you are using C++, you should really be investigating the use of frameworks and class libraries to do this, not writing what will effectively be C code from scratch.

All threads belonging to an application share the global variables of the application, which can thus be used for communication. You will need to protect such multi-threaded access with something like a critical section.

Comment: Indeed i need to create one Thread, and i'm very tight linked to win32 api. I think that CreateThread() could do the job. 
But how can I comunicate between the two threads?