# how to display a table description in system tray using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, system-tray, notify

My table columns are ID(PK),Title,Description.and i want to display the details of the table row values in the system tray,so that when i click the system tray icon,it will display the Title and Description of the table.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can not (AFIK) do that in asp.net.  asp.net code has NO access to local machine resources.  this is a Good Thing (tm) because you don't want any old web site mucking about your computer. this is how viruses and trojans (oh my!) could be spread.  Now, that said, you probably could create a browser plugin or active-x control sort of thing to make it work like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't gain access to the client machine in asp.net through legal way.For winforms:
you can read this post :[What's the proper way to minimize to tray a C# WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/whats-the-proper-way-to-minimize-to-tray-a-c-winforms-app)

Comment: thank you for your repose sir.i want to create a windows app not a web app,so now is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think enough things were said about ASP.NET application accessing local machine. For accessing system tray, please refer to following question and answer: [working with system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593711/working-with-system-tray)