# Multitask with gtk

Tags: c, gtk

How would I run a constant process in the background while there is a gtk system tray icon running? Would I just start two threads and launch the process with one and the system tray icon? Or is there a better way? Sorry, but I am somewhat new to gtk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, then you have an application sitting in the system tray and it needs to periodically check for an external condition.

Your GUI thread can't block for a long time or it would become unresponsive.

I can think of three techniques to solve this:

- Use a timer to periodically poll from the main (GUI) thread ([g_timeout_add()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.28/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) or similar).
- Create a separate thread which runs a busy-wait loop (check for the condition; sleep; check; rinse and repeat). Glib has support for [thread abstraction](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Threads.html) which you could use; [example GThread usage in Brasero](http://git.gnome.org/browse/brasero/tree/libbrasero-media/brasero-drive.c?id=e14152af479a3be29a7125657a0505b65a76a3ad#n937).
- Use asyncronous IO to check for the condition. If you are monitoring a file or directory for changes, then you could use [GFileMonitor](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/2.28/GFileMonitor.html) from GIO.

Comment: I think the second technique would be the best fit, but would the sleep section of the loop cause the program to respond slowly or quickly to the user action depending on when it occurs?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. If you have two separate threads, then one thread (the main/GUI thread) can interact with the user and the other one (the worker thread) can do the work in the background without making the GUI thread unresponsive.

Comment: Ok, what would be the best method to create the thread in this situation? I know there are several different ways such as using an external api or building the class yourself.

Comment: I edited the answer and added two additional links which point to glib's thread abstraction reference manual and example code in Brasero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any threads in your example. What do you exactly call a "constant process"?

Either it is:

- a blocking processing function you made, an you can do your processing in a callback that will be called when your program is idle, by splitting it in several parts (see [g_idle_add](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) and an example of [lazy loading](http://web.archive.org/web/20080321054327/http://log.emmanuelebassi.net/documentation/lazy-loading/))
- or it is what is commmonly called a process (with a PID), and as it runs in a completely separate process, you don't need threads either. Read the official documentation to learn how to [spawn a process](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) from a GTK application.

Comment: Well, The thing will be constantly scanning for something. When something is detected with the scan, it will perform a specified process. The gtk part is only used to specify which process is to be performed when the scan detects something.

Comment: You're still not telling me if you're talking about a processing function or a UNIX process...

Comment: It is a similar situation to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188133/create-a-background-process-with-system-tray-icon